# Collapse (close) Menu in SidebarMenu of Shinydashboard on button click

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive, shinyjs

I am working in an application similar to one below. I have my input panel in sidebar under a menu which is initally expanded. I want to collapse the menu and hide all the input panel so that my sidebar will be clean. But It should appear when I expand (not permanently hide). I tried the following solution but it is not working. Please help me to find a solution or any alternative approach.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        startExpanded = TRUE,
        "Menu 1",
        column(
          width = 12,
          actionButton("hideMe", label = "Collapse Me", icon = icon("close"))
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody()
)
server <- function(input, output, server){
  observeEvent(input$hideMe, {
    shinyjs::hide(selector = "ul.menu-open");
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **`useShinyjs()` into `ui` part**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
        header = dashboardHeader(),
        sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
                useShinyjs(),
                sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem(
                                startExpanded = TRUE,
                                "Menu 1",
                                column(
                                        width = 12,
                                        actionButton("hideMe", label = "Collapse Me", icon = icon("close"))
                                )
                        )
                )
        ),
        body = dashboardBody()
)
server <- function(input, output, server){
        observeEvent(input$hideMe, {
                shinyjs::hide(selector = "ul.menu-open");
        })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Comment: Thanks, the trick is to put `useShinyjs()` in the `ui` section.